# Error Sending Email using PHP, PEAR

Tags: php, pear

I installed Pear and then the Mail and SMTP components on my server. I then updated my php.ini file to "include_path = ".C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear" since that is where the Mail.php is. For some reason when I run this test script through a web browser I get the following errors.

```
Warning: require_once(Mail.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\email.php on line 3
```

and:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\email.php on line 3
```

I'm pretty new to PHP and before last week had never even heard of pear since I normally setup an exchange server. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the test Script.

```
<?php

 require_once "Mail.php";
 $from = "Ty Jacobs <FROM_EMAIL>";
 $to = "Ty Jacobs <TO_EMAIL>";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "ssl://smtp.bizmail.yahoo.com";
 $port = "465";
 $username = "MYUSERNAME";
 $password = "MYPASSWORD";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'port' => $port,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

PHP.INI file:

```
; UNIX: "/path1:/path2"
;include_path = ".:/php/includes"
;
; Windows: "\path1;\path2"
;include_path = ".;c:\php\includes"
include_path=".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')
```

According to this, your pear folder wasn't set up correctly in php.ini. Have you restarted your server?

By the way, you forgot a semicolon in the include path string. It should be:

```
.;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\pear
```

Comment: I did restart the services. I also have the semicolon in the pth in the php.ini. I have added it above so you can see exactly how I added to the .ini.

Comment: Then, you're editing wrong php.ini file. Use `phpconfig()` to get the real php.ini file location. Also maybe there are more include_path definitions in the php.ini that could be the problem too.

Comment: Hast, you were correct. This server has been up for 2 years with no changes made except to update Apache, MySQL, and PHP. I found 4 different PHP.INI files. Thanks you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your WAMP web server after making the change? Neglecting to restart the server after modifying `php.ini` is typically why you'll experience these sorts of issues, because the configuration changes are not read in until the web server is restarted.